# AlertDialog : the background color is not transparent on some devices

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm showing a dialog in an Activity.
I set the background color to transparent by using this code

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

And the dialog background shows transparent, but problems arise when I test my app on some other device.
It shows a white background instead of transparent.
I am not getting how the problem can happen by using the same code in different devices.

Here is my code

```
 final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new     AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_client, null);


             ****** some code*******

        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);          
        alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        // alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Try to use this `dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));`.

Comment: i have tried already, but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `Dialog` instead of `AlertDialog` and your problem will get solved.

Comment: ya its a solutions , but not a correct answer, why this is happen in alert dialog.